# AWS Cloudformation for Quicksight and SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to script Quicksight and Sagemaker as cloudformation scripts? I can't seem to find any cloudformation examples.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/274

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [create SageMaker resources with CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-sagemaker.html). QuickSight however does not have CloudFormation support as of today.